# Include a file from home folder to child using PHP

Tags: php

How to include config.php from home folder to a.php in a new folder?

```
<?php include('../config.php');  ?>
```

This doesnot works

Comment: Yes, using "../" can move the folder outwards (back / up from current folder). You can do this as may folder as you want. Like :-
    <?php include("../../../config.php"); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Normally that should work. Try using `require` instead. `..` is for going one directory back up in the chain. Make sure the file name is right. and try using it with an `echo''` for debugging your config.php if it is included.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/config.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

for example you directory structure is this
root-folder/sub-dir/home.php
and config.php is in the root directory than you code like this.

include('../../config.php');

hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__DIR__` constant. Btw using classes and an autoloader is a much better approach. By include with the wrong code you can have file inclusion vulnerability.